# Wordpress Twenty Thirteen Change from four widgets to three

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Twenty Thirteen theme as a base for a custom child theme that I am creating. The client would like only three widgets in the footer and I need to evenly space them. When I put three widgets there is still room on the right for a fourth (I am not using the sidebar widget, which would knock the 4th widget below the top three).

I found this code in the functions.js file:

```
/**
     * Arranges footer widgets vertically.
     */
    if ( $.isFunction( $.fn.masonry ) ) {
        var columnWidth = body.is( '.sidebar' ) ? 228 : 245;

        $( '#secondary .widget-area' ).masonry( {
            itemSelector: '.widget',
            columnWidth: columnWidth,
            gutterWidth: 20,
            isRTL: body.is( '.rtl' )
        } );
    }
} )( jQuery );
```

It looks like it changes the width but how do I change it to make it only 3 widgets across instead of four?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

The `gutterWidth` option adds additional spacing between columns, but not on the outer sides of the container.  You can alter that value to increase spacing.

However, I think you are going to have to alter other files to properly achieve the task.